# Typescript issues with types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How is possible that this code compiles, it should fail with the type thrown after the first if

```
class Optional<T> {}

class Some<T> extends Optional<T> {
  constructor(public t: T) {
      super()
  }
}

function div(n: number, d: number): Optional<number> {
  if (d === 0.0) {
    return "IMPOSSIBLE"
  }
  return new Some(d / n)
}

console.log(div(1, 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Because TypeScript has a [structual type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) which means it judges type compatibility not by name but by its properties, so an empty class is essentially `any` but for few types like `null` or `undefined`, since it requires none property